# Can not the divide operator be used as argument?

Tags: r

when I ran this code, I got error saying like "unexpected input '/'"

```
m.function <- function(m,n){
if(n==1){
    return(m)
}
else if(n==0){
    return(1)
}
else{
    p <- function(m,n/2)
        if(n%2==0){
            return(p*p)
        }
    else{return(p*p*m)}
}
}
```

Comment: This is just a typo in `p <- function(m,n/2)`. Should that be `p <- m.function(m,n/2)`? R thinks that you are trying to define a function and assign it to `p` (in a context where a function definition makes no sense).

Comment: ahh I changed it to what you suggested, but there is still error like unexpected input on the p<-m.function(m, n/2)

Comment: There also seems to be a typo that `n%2` should be `n%%2`, then you're good to go. Note that although it'll run in most situations, starting the line with else can lead to errors if you run code one line at a time

Comment: Your indentation of the `if` statement below the assignment to `p` certainly makes it appear like you are defining a function. The code isn't very readable when written that way.

Comment: @Miff oh, yeah as you said, when I put odd value into n, I got infinite number...Would you please let me know, how to fix it? if you dont mind

Comment: @최재욱 I can't see immediately, I think that would be a different question, and need a clear specification of what the function is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors here. The typos about `function` vs. `m.function` and the use of `%` instead of `%%`. Also, You are using `n/2` in a context where you need the result to be an integer. For that you need integer division: `%/%`

Corrected:

```
m.function <- function(m,n){
  if(n==1){
    return(m)
  }
  else if(n==0){
    return(1)
  } else {
    p <- m.function(m,n %/% 2)
    if(n %% 2==0){
      return(p*p)
    } else {
      return(p*p*m)
    }
  }
}
```

To explain what you were seeing. At first, `n/2` was interpreted as being inside of the function-defining function `function`. That makes no sense since `n/2` is not a simple variable. When you fix that (and the `%`) but keep `n/2` the problem is that with odd numbers, `n/2` gets outside of the realm of integers.

As an experiment, keep `n/2` and put the line `print(n)` as the first line of the function definition. Then, feed the function an odd `n` and look at the results. For example, If you evaluate `m.function(6,3)` then hundreds of lines are printed, starting with

```
[1] 3
[1] 1.5
[1] 0.75
[1] 0.375
[1] 0.1875
```

and ending with

```
[1] 1.482197e-323
[1] 9.881313e-324
[1] 4.940656e-324
[1] 0
[1] Inf
```

The fact that `n/2` eventually underflows to `0` is what prevents it from going into an infinite recursion (which would cause the function to crash).

Comment: Fraction can't be a argument??